# Can some clarify usage of <include> and <merge>

Tags: android, android-layout, merge, include

I just need someone to tell me if I understood correctly when to use `<include>` and when `<merge>`.

So, I make a header layout which I want to include into some other XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I include it into some other XML this way (which is pretty basic):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will work well, no issue about it. But in order to optimize the code, I have to use `<merge>` in the layout which gets included. So the `top layout` should not have a tag `<LinearLayout>` but it must look like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header text" />
</merge>
```

Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Ya that looks good. Although, in my experience, I don't need merge. I cant just place the text view in its own xml file and include that file. No merge necessary.

Comment: Yes, it will work, but is it **really** safe to use it that way because Google developers never suggested such practice. I am afraid what would happen if they decide to change something which recognizes merge tag.

Comment: @sandalone like everything you will have to update the xml...to the new standard.There has been tons of depreciated methods in android since the beginning so this is not really a problem more of something that one should be mindful of.

Comment: I found this post explains things really well: ["Improve layout performance" on 101apps.co.za](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/improve-layout-performance-use-and.html)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes you understood it correctly. `merge` is used as pseudo parent element to reduce the number of levels in view trees.
Just check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html), it gives very good explanation of `merge`.

In your header file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`<LinearLayout>` doesn't make any difference when your file is included in other file you mentioned. So it's a good thing to use `merge` instead.

Since in XML you must use a single parent element and the rest of the XML elements should be included in it, you should use `merge` as single parent element and can avoid adding unnecessary parent layout.

Just avoid 'merge' when you want to apply a layout differently than layout is defined in file in which your content is inclded.

Comment: Thanks. The link you suggested made a confusion in my head :), and that's I wanted to double-check with you guys.

Comment: @bergnam: Sorry for making confusion.I found it really helpful. Will share if I came across any other good link.

Comment: It's ok. It's the official link after all, and all other texts are based on that one.

Answer (score 38):

From my understanding it will set the merge element as the higher element in the view hierarchy. Include will simply put the whole viewgroup in there. So using your example the view hierarchy should look like:

With merge:

```
LinearLayout (root)
|
TextView
```

With include:

```
LinearLayout (root)
|
LinearLayout
|
TextView
```

So you will have an extra LinearLayout in the view hierarchy that you do not need. However, sometimes you need that intermediate view. In your case, you wouldn't, since both the LinearLayouts have the same layout params and no other differences.