# Equivalent of transclusion in Android

Tags: android

As an angular developer learning Android, I've found I'm missing transclusion.

Imagine I have a layout which contains a kind of structure for the app, something like

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    >

    <!--Header-->
    <TextView
        ...
        />

    <!--Content-->
    <include layout="foo"/>

    <!--Footer-->
    <TextView
        ...
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want to copy paste this structure to every layout in my app, as it grows it quickly becomes unwieldy to modify.

**What is the Android way of tackling this problem?**

Comment: Use `<include>`, as you are already doing. Or, create a custom `ViewGroup` to represent this structure from a single layout resource. Or, if this represents a screen, have a `Fragment` that uses this structure from a single layout resource.

Comment: `<include layout="foo"/>` you are already using it

Answer (score 2):

Keep your common layout in a file say **common_ui.xml** then you can include it in any other layout you want using include tag.

```
<include layout="@layout/common_ui"/>
```

There is also **merge** tag which can be used when your **common_ui** only has views i.e. you don't want to add ViewGroups as parents then you should use merge to keep view hierarchy flatten.
[Check this answer to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196501/can-some-clarify-usage-of-include-and-merge)